# Connection Info (ACS) for biztalk service on Azure Portal with a Free Trial subscription

Tags: azure, biztalk-services

I recently created my free trial account on Azure and need to deploy a biztalk service project for which Namespace and Issuer Secret are needed(which were automatically created as per documentation when I created the biztalk service on azure portal).

Apparently I can't see any Access Connection Information on the portal, there is only one setting = Delete, available in the bottom tool bar.

Is it not available on free trial account for biztalk services? Connection information is required for visual studio integration of the biztalk services as well.

Answer (score 0):

Beside that you created a free trial account you also (supposedly) created a `free` edition of BizTalk service.

Well, the free edition is yet in preview and apparently does not have these features. Frankly I am not sure what goes with the Free edition of BizTalk service.

But when you create a `paid` version of BizTalk service - Developer or higher edition, you will all the information you need (and all the buttons on the bottom bar).